# J2ME WMA Delivery Report

Tags: java-me, report, wma

What's the best way to implement delivery report in J2ME WMA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't achieve this with j2me. For more info see the existing nokia [forum discussion](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=BdD&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=+site%3adiscussion.forum.nokia.com+delivery+report+%2B+j2me&sa=X&ei=EqBGTZXQJpCrrAeArZDwDw&ved=0CB8QrQIwAA&cad=h).